# How could I create dynamic WebDav configurations using Django and web server?

Tags: django, webdav

I have a Django web app that provides a download facility for a private user dropbox by issuing HTTP requests to a lighttpd server using the x-send-file header. I would like to extend this functionality to allow WebDav access from third party clients. Is this possible? The only examples I can see have  statically defined WebDav folders.

The only example of a per-user dynamic WebDAV confir I can find is [this solution using the Apache LA-U look-ahead feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700480/control-access-to-webdav-apache-using-python).

I'd love to extend my Django app for this but the key requirement is to be able to generate a dynamic config. Integration with a third party solution would be OK.

Any suggestions?

Michela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing. I also wanted to use other parts of Django with WebDAV, so I started the django-webdav project.

http://code.google.com/p/django-webdav/

At this point it is working (passes litmus basic + movecopy tests) and I can use it with Windows and Linux (DAVfs2).

Check it out and help out if you think it suits your needs.

Comment: I am interested in using this for an open application to store legislation from around the world. Does django-webdav only work with the internal django server? Is it production-ready?

Comment: Ari, it will work with any hosting mechanism such as mod_wsgi (what I test on). I would NOT consider it production ready, but close. Unfortunately this project has been delayed so I have not yet finished it. I will however once I finish some other projects. As always patches are happily accepted!

Comment: Thanks so much, btimby.  I am still interested in Django-WebDav integration for our project, but am not quite enough of a server ninja to provide patches yet!